# okhttp client websocket failing

Tags: java, android, kotlin, websocket, okhttp

I am using okhttp library to connect my local websocket server (android app).

```
    val request = Request.Builder().url("ws://localhost:3334/").build()
    val wsClient = OkHttpClient().newWebSocket(request, webSocketListener)
    Logger.log("WebSocketHandler", "${serialiser.toJson(wsClient.request())}")
```

And webSocketListener

```
val webSocketListener = object : WebSocketListener() {
      override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
         Logger.i("WebSocketListener_onOpen", "Response: ${serialiser.toJson(response)}")
    }

    override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
        Logger.i("WebSocketListener_onMessage", "text: $text")
    }

    override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket,
                           bytes: ByteString) {
        Logger.i("WebSocketListener_onMessage", "text: ${serialiser.toJson(bytes)}")
    }

    override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket,
                           code: Int, reason: String) {
        Logger.i("WebSocketListener_onClosing", "reason: $reason, code: $code")
    }

    override fun onClosed(webSocket: WebSocket,
                          code: Int, reason: String) {
        Logger.i("WebSocketListener_onClosed", "reason: $reason, code: $code")
    }

    override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket,
                           throwable:Throwable,
                           response: Response?) {
        Logger.i("WebSocketListener_onFailure", "Response: ${serialiser.toJson(throwable)}")
    }
}
```

But, when I try to run the app the connection establishment failing with logs

```
[socket]:check permission begin!
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out: [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils

// throwable object
{
    "cause": {
        "cause": {
            "errno": 111,
            "stackTrace": [],
            "suppressedExceptions": []
        },
        "detailMessage": "failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 3334) from /127.0.0.1 (port 49040) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)",
        "stackTrace": [],
        "suppressedExceptions": []
    },
    "detailMessage": "Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:3334",
    "stackTrace": [],
    "suppressedExceptions": []
}
```

onFailure is called before even establishing the connection. The websocket server is working fine (tested separately with nodeJS client)

I couldn't event get the proper error message. Can someone help me out

Answer (score -1):

Its a build problem. The file system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar is not in the jar (or not on the classpath)